# Dell server with NIC that won't show link up

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nic

I have a dell server (PowerEdge R330) and I have just tried to liven up the second on board NIC.  idrac says it is connected as does poking into the lifecycle setup on boot but ethtool says it isn't and eno2 (this is ubuntu 16.04) does not appear in ifconfig in spite of being set up in network/interfaces.

```
auto eno2
iface eno1 inet static
        address 130.216.30.231
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    broadcast 130.216.30.255
    gateway 130.216.30.254
```

Ethtool show link as down.

the one thing that I can see different is that idrac shows the second (problematic) NIC as

`OS Driver State : Non Operational`

the other says `Operational`

any thoughts on what to try next?

Comment: Is that a typo? You have put in `eno1` instead of `eno2`.

Comment: DOH!   this isn't the first time I have sat staring at a config file for ages and not seen a glaring error.   Thank you!